# JPA/HSQLDB is still eating all my memory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I'm working on a program that parses data from a file and stores it into a HSQLDB database. As the parser encounters data it creates entities which are mapped to the database using JPA/Hibernate. **My problem is that while the parsing is being performed the application uses more and more memory.** I have successfully used cached tables so that once the parsing is complete the memory is all released, but during the parsing it uses way more than what I am comfortable with.

I have tried to fix this by calling `flush` and `clear` methods on my EntityManager, but this had no effect. I've also tried to make sure that Entity with references to all other entities is kept in memory.

The largest objects in memory seems to be hsqldb.Sessions. Could it be that HSQlDb caches loads of data for each transaction? It does seem excessive to need 1GB of RAM to only end up with a DB that is 120MB on disk does it not?

Please advise on what I could try next.

Comment: Try manually flushing entity manager while persisting entities. Calling EntityManager.flush() may clear unnecessary referrences in the memory. But im not sure if it will solve your problem.

Comment: @feridcelik  - I am currently flushing and then clearing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of faffing around with HSQLDB I followed the advice of two friends and changed database to H2. The memory footprint during a transaction is roughly a third now and it is also 20% faster.

Really surprised me

Comment: Looks like you've been using HSQLDB 1.8.x. The transaction memory use of HSQLDB 2.0.x with CACHED tables is much lower.

Comment: @fredt - Thanks for that. It's too late now to go back to HSQLDB, but for my next project I'll give it another go :)

Answer (score 2):

Do a heap dump and use [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to analyse where the memory is used.  With JPA the results are often surprising and without looking at the actual memory usage you're often stabbing in the dark.

Comment: good sueggestion as I have no idea why this is happening. I just thought clearing the EntityManager would release all the memory.

Comment: This revealed that it is HSQLDB that is holding on to the memory for some reason. Does it mean it is a database configuration problem, or a application design problem, or a transactional design problem? :)

Comment: Which classes use the most memory?

Answer (score 0):

It could be different causes. I'd like to describe tools for memory leaks analysis:
1) first, find the process_id in your task manager;

2) then take a heap dump:

```
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=<filename> <process_id>
```

3) then analyse it:
a) JHAT util:

```
jhat <file>
```

b) (i recommend to) install Eclipse Memory Analyzer plugin from

```
http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.3/update-site/
```

(Eclipse: help-> install new software ->add repository )

install it and go to its perspective. 
open  and select option to find memory leaks.

In case of HSQLDB:
usually MemoryAnalizer shows that memory used in

```
CompiledStatementManager.csidmap
```

-then make sure that you always call

```
statement.close()
```